# How to change getter property argument and display different result?

Tags: php

```
class Session{
    public static $instance = null;
    public $name = '';
    public $value = '';

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if (self::$instance == null)
    {
        self::$instance = new Session();
    }
        return self::$instance;
}   

    public function setProperty($key,$value){
        $this->name = $key;
        $this->value = $value;
    }
    public function getProperty(){
        return $this->name;
        return $this->value;
    }
}


?>
$session= new Session;
$session=Session::getInstance();
$session->setProperty('name','Bob');
echo "<h1>{$session->getProperty('value')}</h1>";
```

Is it possible to have argument in getProperty()?

How can I display Bob by using `$session->getProperty('value')`

I want to change the argument in getProperty to display the result I want.

Comment: the get property function has two return statements and you know that only one will work right?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're trying to create a class that can set and retrieve multiple properties, so I'd recommend that you use an associative array to achieve that. For example...

```php
class Session
{
    public static $instance;

    protected $properties = [];

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (! self::$instance instanceof static) {
            self::$instance = new Session();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }   

    public function setProperty($key, $value)
    {
        $this->properties[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function getProperty($key, $default = null)
    {
        if (! isset($this->properties[$key])) {
            return $default;
        }

        return $this->properties[$key];
    }
}
```

Now you'll be able to do the following...

```php
$session = Session::getInstance();

$session->setProperty('name', 'Bob');
$session->setProperty('age', 69);

$session->getProperty('name'); // 'Bob'
$session->getProperty('age'); // 69
$session->getProperty('height'); // null
$session->getProperty('height', 'N/A'); // 'N/A'
```